# Why is JavaScript UpdateExpression syntax so defined?

Tags: javascript, syntax, language-design

According to Ecma-262, prefix increment and decrement operators are defined as:

```
UpdateExpression :
    LeftHandSideExpression ++
    LeftHandSideExpression ‐‐
    ++ UnaryExpression
    ‐‐ UnaryExpression
```

This is surprising, both that the postfix and prefix operators are defined in the same rule, and that it's `++ UnaryExpression` when surely a unary expression in general is not actually a valid argument for the update operators.

It would seem cleaner and more logical to define the prefix increment and decrement operators in `UnaryExpression` itself, along with the other prefix operators, and other C syntax languages do this, e.g. the C standard section 6.5.3 defines `unary-expression` to include the prefix update operators along with the others.

Why does JavaScript define these operators the way it does?

Comment: I can't begin to claim to quite understand the decisions made for the grammar productions in the spec, thus cannot post an answer I (or you!) would be happy with, but two things I can observe for you: The spec frequently groups related syntax expressions together in this way, and separately, the issue of not all UnaryExpressions being valid targets is handled [by a static semantics early error](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-update-expressions-static-semantics-early-errors).

Comment: @melpomene Is it? It would be if ++ was specified to take a call expression, but for some reason it's actually specified to take a unary expression which in turn can be another update expression, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: In ES6, they *are* defined in `UnaryExpression`: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-operators

Comment: …which makes me wonder what the difference is. ES8 has `await` as a unary expression, but surely that never returns a reference?

Comment: @Bergi So they are. I was working from the 2017 version, which means they were previously defined in the intuitively obvious way, then changed to the unintuitive way. That makes it even weirder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does JavaScript define these operators the way it does?

It's mostly historical, as so many other oddities in the spec.

> It would seem cleaner and more logical to define the prefix increment and decrement operators in `UnaryExpression` itself, along with the other prefix operators, and other C syntax languages do this

In fact, that's how it was defined for many years, in [ES5.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4) and [ES6](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-operators). It's simple, and has one syntactic production per precedence level (`PostfixExpression` being the next-tighter one), and was probably directly inherited from the C or Java grammar when JS was conceived.

> Surely a unary expression in general is not actually a valid argument for the update operators

In C, `-- -- x` is actually valid, so that's why the prefix increment and decrement operator expressions contain another `UnaryExpression`. Of course, it would throw an exception when trying to evaluate the expression, but parsing it would work fine in ES5.

ES6 then added the concept of *early errors*, and increment and decrement operations now [required a valid assignment target expression](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-operators-static-semantics-early-errors) upon parsing. This was not encoded in the syntactical productions though.

> It is surprising that the postfix and prefix operators are defined in the same rule

This definition is [new in ES7](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-unary-operators). It changed with [this commit](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/commit/28bdf0798662bcb8efb11c4070f8a981a496ccc1) that introduced the *exponentiation operator*, where the `PostfixExpression` was renamed to `UpdateExpression` and the prefix operators were moved into the rule. Some change like that was necessary because the `**` operator allows an update expression, but not a `UnaryExpression` as its first argument (because unary minus, as in `-x ** 3`, was deemed  too ambiguous).